# Jstack fails after two weeks of normal work

Tags: java, jstack

I have dockerized tomcat 7.0.73 based on `java:7-jdk` docker image.

I have a job that every 5 minutes does thread dump with command `jstack 1`. It works for about two weeks normally and after that crashes with message:

`Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded. The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding`
Exit code is 1.

What can be the cause of this behavior?

JVM keeps working okay. Space looks correct too.

`java -version
java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)`

`Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-202:1-xxx   10G 1013M  9.1G  10% /
tmpfs                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                          3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1                     99G   68G   31G  69% /tmp
shm                            64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm`

Comment: Maybe you run of of sockets?

Comment: If I had to guess, I suspect that a process may be clearing out old files in `/tmp`, and it's taking the relevant `/tmp/.java_pid` socket file with it (which is required by utilities such as jstack.) Next time it happens look to see if the relevant file is still there - if not, then that's your issue.

Comment: @berry120 I think you're right, we have cleanup job for /tmp. File is not there, I can see it. Please post your answer and I mark it as solution. Thanks!

Comment: @snowindy No problem, happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that a process may be clearing out old files in `/tmp`, and it's taking the relevant `/tmp/.java_pid` socket file with it (which is required by utilities such as jstack.) Next time it happens look to see if the relevant file is still there - if not, then that's your issue.